# Plot average salaries on a world map python

Tags: python, data-analysis, world-map, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a list of countries, and the salaries for people in those countries

Using the data I have been able to calculate the average salary for each country. I want to visualize it on a world map with legend, where green would represent a certain range of salary, red another range and so on

How do I visualize my data on a world map like this? I cannot find any libraries

Comment: Look into bokeh, geopandas, leaflet, or folium

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-an-interactive-geographical-map-using-python-f4c5197e23e0

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

while I agree that this question is rather vague, here are the 2 steps you need to do to get it working:

1. go to [NaturalEarth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com) and get yourself a shapefile with all the countries in the world (e.g. the `Admin 0 – Countries` dataset)
   https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/
2. read the shapefile with geopandas, identify your countries, add the values as a column to the geo-dataframe and plot the data by following the instructions in their docs
   https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html